# Easy way to create AudioGrams, ideally with waveform & Subtitles / Closed Captions with progressing marker on them? Free to start with?

Tags: audio, subtitles

**Easy way to create AudioGrams, ideally with waveform & Subtitles / Closed Captions with progressing marker on them? Free to Start with?**

1. Easy way to take my writings; quotes, poems or short insights into video with Narrated voice over,

   1. Ideally with waveform &
   2. A karaoke style or jumping/ progressing cursor/ marker on the text - Subtitle/ Captions?
2. Keeping some chosen static background image or the writing as an image.

Basically, give my writings a little bit of voice, diction, feel, vibe.

- Thoughts/ suggestions on simpler easy mobile apps that can be used to this?

Or a

- SIMPLER - REPEATABLE way to use a Video Editor for this PURPOSE? without having to master A VIDEO EDITOR?

Answer (score 0):

Setting up an automated pipeline for this would take days for a trained person, weeks for someone who doesn't work in the industry. I would recommend you use After-Effects for those motion-graphics. Trapcode sound-keys has very good possibilities for audio-spectrums and wave-forms. Animating the text and highlighting it, karaoke-style would be quite easy. However, both After-Effects and Trapcode (by Red Giant) come with a cost.